# Avoiding "Could not resolve view with name ''." when redirecting with Spring Webflux?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have an Spring Boot 2.1 application whose configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebFlux
internal class RestConfig : WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Bean
    fun forwardedHeaderTransformer() = ForwardedHeaderTransformer()

    override fun configureHttpMessageCodecs(configurer: ServerCodecConfigurer) {
        // Some configuration
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to permanently redirect requests to `/` to `/api` using this:

```
@GetMapping("/")
fun redirectToApi(req: ServerHttpRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
    return ServerResponse.permanentRedirect(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/api")).build()
}
```

But when I call `/` (for example using `curl http://localhost:8080`) I get an error instead of a redirect:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2019-03-29T13:47:29.054+0000",
  "path": "/",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Could not resolve view with name ''.",
  "exception": "java.lang.IllegalStateException"
}
```

Why is this and how can I solve it?